# Angular 7- custom controls

Tags: angular

I have a custom control that is used at 2 places.How can I differentiate the textbox and button used in these 2 different places

Below are the 2 places am using the custom control

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <label
            >EmailAddresses</label
          >
          <app-custom
            [control]="control.emailAddresses"
          ></app-string-stack>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <label
            >AlternativeNames</label
          >
          <app-custom
            [control]="control.alternativeNames"
            readonly="true"
          ></app-string-stack>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


This is the actual custom control that has text box and button

<div>
  <div
    *ngFor="let ctrl of control.controls; let i=index"
    class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2"
  >
    <input class="form-control" [formControl]="ctrl" [readOnly]="readonly" />

    <button>
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <button *ngIf="!readonly" class="btn btn-info" (click)="add()" l10nTranslate>
    controls/string-stack/button.Add
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean under "differentiate" exactly?

Comment: Hi Robert, Am trying to support automation testing,So when I give ids to the textbox and button.It is the same at both the places.And am not able to differentiate the textbox, button at 2 different places.Please let me know how I can give different ids at different instances

Comment: In order to help you, would you please post more of your code and explain more what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do property binding to [id].

Something like this:

```
<input class="form-control" [id]="prefix + i" [formControl]="ctrl" [readOnly]="readonly" />
```

"prefix" could come in as an `@Input() prefix: string;` for the custom control and `i` is just the index from the `*ngFor`

Using like this in same html twice with different prefix values:

```
<app-custom prefix="some-name" [control]="control.emailAddresses"></app-custom>
<app-custom prefix="other-name" [control]="control.emailAddresses"></app-custom>
```

Comment: @Nihali Wonderful! Please mark this as the answer if it solved your issue :) Thank you!